# There is any possibility to plot DateTime values over X Axis in the same order they are read from List<>?

Tags: c#

I have a file with following format:

[image]

I'm saving each column into a List<> and then I'm trying to plot st_DateTime over int_class. My expectation is to see 10 points, one for each row, in the same order as they are from the file.
But, if I'm using x-values as DateTime I'm getting only 6 points.
But, if I'm using x-values as string, for the further series that will be added I will have to insert dummy points in order to have  aligned series which is a mess if I have thousands of points.

Could someone help me with this? There is any possibility to plot x-values as DateTime but not chronologically, meaning in the same order as they are read from the files?

Update:
This is my result if I'm using string for x-values. I have both items which are recorded at the same time but the series are not aligned.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2D9UP.png)

If I'm converting to DateTime I will have only one item and I don't want this. I don't want duplicate items to be overlapped.
There is any chance to do this?
Or any free library which I can use it? (i also used NPlot library but result was the same).

Thanks

Comment: What code are you using to plot your values? What library are you using to plot? This isn't just a c# issue...

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, won't some of your point overlap? How do you expect to see 2 points for the first 2 items for example? The `st_DateTime` and `int_class` are the exact same in both, so they'll plot to the exact same coordinates, no?

Comment: Do you have a `List<DateTime>` a List<string > and a List<int>? Also don’t forget to remove the square brackets before and after the dates

Comment: It would really help to have a mock-up of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Why don't you sort list by Time which is the normal way of solving these issues.

Comment: @Jason W - I'm using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting reference for plotting data.

Comment: Sorting the list will not solve my issue. I need to plot the points as they are read from the file and I also need to see the points which are overlap.